# Send Dynamic data to Azure Logic app based on fixed schedule

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-scheduler

I've a logic app, let's name it as 'LA1' having HTTP trigger. This logic app can accept multiple request types (see Request 1 and Request 2 below) and can call respective nested logic apps based on request fields -

Request 1 -

{

"Format":"F1",

"Time":"T1"

}

Request 2 -

{

"Format":"F2",

"Time":"T2"

}

Now I wanted the above requests to be sent to LA1 on specific time intervals. Say Request 1 to be sent to LA1 every 1 minute and Request 2 to be sent to LA1 every 2 minutes. This was accomplished successfully using Scheduler Job Collections in Azure portal where I'd create couple of schedulers to run every 1 or 2 minutes and configure Request 1 and Request 2 in them.

Now that as Microsoft has retired Scheduler Job Collections I would like to know different alternate options in hand to send dynamic data (scheduled at specific intervals) to LA1 Logic app.

I understand that creating multiple logic apps with recurrence trigger and passing different JSON is one option however I would like to avoid the same as I would end up creating too many logic apps and in case of any changes this would need a deployment of Logic apps on every environment.

I would like to have something that's configurable (one time configuration on every environment) something that was catered perfectly by Scheduler Job Collections. Any thoughts/ideas are much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One choice is Azure Function, it has Timer Trigger binding, it uses CRON expressions to define your schedule. Further more information you could refer to this doc: [Timer trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer).

Also Azure provides Azure Automation and the Azure Automation supports schedule a runbook. You could use powershell to manage schedules. Further more details you could check this doc: [Scheduling a runbook in Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/schedules).

Comment: Thanks George! Azure Function with Timer binding is something that I had explored before however for my usecase we would need to create multiple Azure Functions. 
Azure runbook is something that I can try exploring, thanks for suggestions!

Comment: @mitesh patel, any update now? Could you send it now?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet George...I tried a bit using graphic runbook cmdlets but didn't find any cmdlet there with respect to azure logic apps....I didn't get much time to spend on it as I was caught up with some other issues...I'll spend some time on this in 2-3 days maybe and let you know in case it works...thanks for checking though!